# Unable to run IIS7 site from shared folder on linux

Tags: linux, iis, vmware

I have an IIS 7 application that runs fine locally, but for various reasons, needs to be ran from a Linux share (Arch 4.8.7-1, ext4 file system). IIS is running on a Win8.1 professional install on the latest VMWare-Player, and the share is through the VMWare player shared folders. I'm able to open the project via Visual Studio, but when I attempt to run it in IIS, I get a permissions issue. However, the folder on the host has full rwx permissions, and any user I log into is able to successfully access the files in question.

After running ProcMon, I found this:

```
1:10:18.0982351 PM  w3wp.exe    4564    NotifyChangeDirectory   \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Dev\XXX\WEBSITE    INVALID DEVICE REQUEST  Filter: FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_EA, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_STREAM_NAME, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_STREAM_SIZE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_STREAM_WRITE
```

I've applied the No Change Notify hotfix, as well as the registry changes to enforce it, but no luck in getting it to actually work.

Is there any way to enable NotifyChangeDirectory on an ext4 filesystem? Or to just disable this "Feature" entirely?

IIS error:

```
Module
   IIS Web Core 
Notification
   BeginRequest 
Handler
   Not yet determined 
Error Code
   0x80070001 
Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file  
Config File
   \\?\Z:\XXX\WEBSITE\web.config
```

(Note: Z:\ points to \vmware-host\Shared Folders\dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, of course, I found the answer right after posting it. I found this blog:

https://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/list-of-registry-keys-affecting-iis7-behavior

which showed a bunch of registry keys. I added

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters\ConfigPollMilliSeconds (REG_DWORD)
```

and set it to FFFFFFFF. After a reboot, it worked like a dream. Note that you'll want to change it to something lower (Maybe 60k?) if you're actually doing development.

Comment: Cool. Does procmon still show NotifyChangeDirectory event with INVALID DEVICE REQUEST message.